# what is the code for this?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given two arrays as below :

```
var searchResultsArray = [{"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, {"username": "def", "userid": 45646}, {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}…..]; // size is 100

var connectionsResultsArray = [{"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, {"username": "xyz", "userid": 7868}, {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}…..]; // size is 300
```

Enhance the first array (`searchResultsArray`) to have a flag, say connected, which is set to 'yes' if the element exists in the second array and 'no' otherwise.

### sample ouput from above :

```
var connectedSearchResultsArray = [{"username": "abc", "userid": 23213, "connected": "yes"}, {"username": "def", "userid": 45646,  "connected": "no"}, {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898, , "connected": "yes"}…..]; // size is 100
```

Comment: Nice homework question you got there :) You should probably do it yourself.

Comment: At least, try to solve it yourself first (and, show some of that effort in your question). [We're not against assisting with homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions), but we are against just handing you a solution.

Comment: var searchResultsArray = [
        {"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, 
        {"username": "def", "userid": 45646}, 
        {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}];
var connectionsResultsArray = [
        {"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, 
        {"username": "xyz", "userid": 7868}, 
        {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}];
angular.forEach(searchResultsArray,function(item){
    angular.forEach(connectionsResultsArray,function(obj){
        if(obj[item.userid] == item.userid){
            item.connected = 'yes';
        } else{
            item.connected = 'no';
        }
    });
})

Comment: I don't know, what does your output tell you?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply iterate over the first array, and within that iteration then iterate over the second to make your comparison. But that would be O(n^2), which is not ideal at all.

Instead, you can store the second array in a hash table and then iterate over the first array once and find out if its key exists within the hash. If it does, then you can append it that way. This gives O(n) time complexity, which is so much better than the brute force method I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this would be to create a dictionary of the items in your second (`connectionsResultsArray`) so that lookup time is fast (`O(1)`) and then iterate of your first array (`searchResultsArray`) and check for matches:

```
var searchResultsArray = [{"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, {"username": "def", "userid": 45646}, {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}];
var connectionsResultsArray = [{"username": "abc", "userid": 23213}, {"username": "xyz", "userid": 7868}, {"username": "ghi", "userid": 9898}];

// I'm assuming userid is sufficient to determine uniqueness
var useridToConnectionsResultMap = {};

for (var i = 0; i < connectionsResultsArray.length; i++) {
  var connectionsResult = connectionsResultsArray[i];
  useridToConnectionsResultMap[connectionsResult.userid] = connectionsResult;
}

for (var i = 0; i < searchResultsArray.length; i++) {
  var searchResult = searchResultsArray[i];
  searchResult.connected = useridToConnectionsResultMap[searchResult.userid] ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

This way your runtime would be `O(n+m)` where `n` and `m` are the number of items in your arrays.

The solution you mentioned in a comment to your original question would have a much larger worst-case runtime (O(`n * m)`) because you're potentially walking through the full second array for each item in the first array (if there are no matches). This matters a lot when you're dealing with large collections (or just in general, because it's a bad habit to be in).